# single exposed filter for two displays in same view

Tags: ajax, views

I have three displays in same view. Every display has exposed form filter and in every pages ajax was set yes. How to use a single exposed filter for these three displays in same view?

I placed these three displays in to three quick tabs. For example, the three quicktabs names are test1, test2, test3. If I apply filter in test1, it should apply all other displays (test2, test3) also.

Answer (score 0):

1. Under Advanced > Other You have to set the "Use AJAX:Yes" for both the views.
2. At the Quick tab setting page select the following radio button -
   Yes: Load only the first tab on page view".

Comment: Why would it not work when using the "No: Load all tabs on page view" option?